# Issue when fetching Document information from a Record Filenet

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I am facing a issue where I am not able to get the document information associated with the record.
The line below is used to get a particular record,

**com.ibm.jarm.api.core.Record r = RMFactory.Record.fetchInstance(jarmFPOS, "{AE10E0F1-323F-4445-A529-78F744E8D3E4}", null);**

Now that I have a record object I need to fetch the document information such as DocId, DocTitle, DocOwner etc..I know that the required information is stored in a property called as “RecordedDocuments” or we can use RMProperty.DOCUMENT_LINK from which we can get the value. I am using something like below.

**Object obj3 = (Object) r.getProperties().get(RMProperty.DOCUMENT_LINK).getObjectValue();**

My issue is here. I am not able to get the values from the Object. I tried typecasting it to a document object but no luck. I keep on getting typecasting error. Can anyone please help me how to get the desired output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Link object would not be a document directly... I'm not very familiar with RM APIs, more with CE APIs, but it would probably be an implementation of the [RMLink](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSNVVQ_5.1.2/com.ibm.p8.ier.dev.java.jarm.doc/index.html?com/ibm/jarm/api/core/RMLink.html) interface.

What I usually do in such a case is print out the java class name of the object (`obj3.getClass().getName()`) and that would give you a good indication on which API object you can use.

Answer (score 0):

May be because it was a list and not a Document that fails the casting? Try what polonoko told you and print the className.

Or try this code :)

```
List<com.filenet.api.core.Document> doc = (List<com.filenet.api.core.Document>) r.getProperties().get(RMProperty.DOCUMENT_LINK).getObjectValue();
```